# Почему меняется значение переменной?

Tags: c#

Не могу понять, почему меняется значение переменной "a"?

```
int a = 5;
        int res1 = a++;
        int res2 = a++;
        int res = res1 + res2;
        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, res1= {1}, res2 ={2}, res={3}", a, res1, 
        res2, res);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `a++` эквивалентно `a=a+1`, а вы это вызываете аж 2 раза

Comment: [Оператор ++ (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator)

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, почему должна меняться сама переменная “a”?

Comment: Потому что операторы ++ и --так работают - они меняют переменную, к которой применяются.

Comment: @LevKostychenko, а какой смысл в операторе `++` по-Вашему? Т.е. есть в языке оператор `+`, зачем нужен ещё и `++`?

Comment: Для удобства. Но `++a` увеличивает значение после его выполнения, в отличии от `a = a + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем [справочник по C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator), читаем:

> Оператор инкремента (++) **увеличивает операнд на 1**. Оператор инкремента
>   может находиться перед своим операндом или после него: ++variable и
>   variable++.

В первом случае инкремент называется [префиксным](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy3d35h8.aspx), во втором - [постфиксным](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e1e3921c.aspx).

Таким образом, вы этим оператором и увеличили переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не так представляете себе работу оператора инкремента ++: вы, должно быть, хотели использовать его, чтобы получить значение, большее `a` на 1. Для этого необходимо использовать выражение вида `a + 1`.
Оператор `++` же изменяет значение той переменной, по отношению к которой применяется. Выражение `b = a++;` логически соответствует `b = a; a = a + 1;`
Если `++` поставить не после переменной, а перед ней: `b = ++a;`, то инкремент будет выполнен до использования значения переменной в выражении: `a = a + 1; b = a;`

Аналогично для оператора декремента `--`.

Answer (score 0):

Все базовые типы (`int, float, double` и т.п) кроме типа `string` являются `ValueType` т.е они в памяти размещены в стеке и не передаются, а копируются. Другими словами вы берете и копируете **значение** переменной `a` в переменную `res1` и после того как вы скопировали **значение** отрабатывает операция `++` которая изменяет **значение** вашей переменной `а`, увеличивая его на единицу. Другими словами, после выполнения кода

```
int res1 = a++;
```

переменные приобретают следующие значения

```
а = 6;
res1 = 5;
```

С типом `string` все иначе, вы копируете не значение переменной, а ссылку на значение(находящиеся в памяти)